# Distribute the row of a reference evenly when copying and pasting formulas in excel? (Pic included)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm trying to spread this list out between gaps but the row number in the formula keeps skipping ahead.

I want to copy the =$A1, and when I paste it I want it to to show up as =$A2 instead of =$A4 because of the gaps.

[Picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMJvg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to understand your description, but I guess you mean this:

[image]

```
=IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$B$1001;MATCH(F5;$B$2:$B$1001;0);1);"")
```

Comment: yeah turns out helper columns are what i needed to know about! thank you!!